# '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Movie''

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm getting this error :

> '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter
>   searching for entity name 'Movie''

Whenever I try and save something to coreData and am wondering how can I get rid of it.  I searched online but looks like most of the answers given are in objective-c when a swift solution is needed. If it makes any difference I added the coreData manually after the project was already created. It was made sure all the boiler plate code was copied over to AppDelegate for coreData. This is how the data is being saved:

```
  func saveToCoreData(id: NSNumber) {

    guard let appDelegate =
      UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext =
      appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =
      NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Movie",
                                 in: managedContext)!

    let id = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                 insertInto: managedContext)

    id.setValue(id, forKeyPath: "id")

    do {
      try managedContext.save()
      savedCoreDataMovieIdArray.append(id)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt what's causing the issue, but I believe that you need to call appDelegate to save the context. Just to make sure what's causing the issue:

```
func saveToCoreData(id: NSNumber) {

  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
  let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Movie", in: managedContext)

  let id = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

  id.setValue(id, forKeyPath: "id")

  do {
    try appDelegate.save()
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

If it's not solved, please share a screenshot of your CoreData model.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was, since I copy and pasted boiler plate code from another project, it was still using that projects name for the persistent storage.

Comment: @SwiftyJD if that is your solution then please post an answer to yourself so that other viewers can see it.